# Highcharts - Chose category via dropdown list

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I'm fairly new to working with Highcharts. As it is right now I am trying to figure out a way to let the user browse between categories via a *drop-down* selection.

The chart itself is quite simple: Categories are months, Jan through Dec, and the data arrays are populated by looping through SharePoint list data.

What I am hoping to be able to create is a solution where the user can choose which month to view data for via a drop-down selection. This would have to be done after all data has been loaded into the chart to avoid having to query the service for each selection.

The **charts-code** itself is very simple:

```
$('#container3').highcharts({
chart: {
    type: 'column'
},
title: {
    text: ''
},
subtitle: {
    text: ''
},
xAxis: {
    categories: categoryMonthsArray,
    crosshair: true
},
yAxis: {
    min: 0,
    title: {
        text: ''
    }
},
tooltip: {
    headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:10px">{point.key}</span><table>',
    pointFormat: '<tr><td style="color:{series.color};padding:0">{series.name}: </td>' +
    '<td style="padding:0"><b>{point.y:.0f}</b></td></tr>',
    footerFormat: '</table>',
    shared: true,
    useHTML: true
},
plotOptions: {
    column: {
        pointPadding: 0.2,
        borderWidth: 0
    }
},
series: [{
    name: 'd1',
    data: d1Array
}, {
    name: 'd2',
    data: d2Array
}, {
    name: 'd3',
    data: d3Array
}, {
    name: 'd4',
    data: d4Array
}, {
    name: 'd5',
    data: d5Array
}]
```

Any pointers at all would be very much appreciated here!

Comment: What does "can choose which month to view data for" mean? From my understanding that would just be showing f.x. X-value 0 (January) as the only thing on the chart...?

Comment: On select use some dynamic methods to update data in the series - you can use series.update() or series.setData() http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/Series.setData See the example http://jsfiddle.net/6mz449k6/

Comment: That's perfect, thanks a lot!